# onTouchEvent does not work when the view is in a layout

Tags: java, android, layout, ontouchlistener

I have created a class MapView that draws some circles and lines representing a map, where you can touch a circle to change the color of it. If works as it should, but when I add the View to a Layout the touchlistener does not return any touches.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MapView mapView;
RelativeLayout mainLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mapView = new MapView(this);
    mapView.findViewById(R.id.theMap2);
    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                System.out.println("Touch! X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
                mapView.touched(x, y);
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}
```

I can see that the mapView works by doing this: `setContentView(mapView);`

Here is activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <bus.com.ece602_bus.MapView
        android:id="@+id/theMap2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are the touches not registered?

Comment: why are you trying to find the view (`mapView.findViewById(R.id.theMap2);`)  but don't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);` creates a new layout with a new instance of `MapView` than the one you set the listener for.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize it worked like that, moved up setContentView and now it works!